# Mapbox not working in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, mapbox

I am trying to display a mapbox in a fragment but I am getting the following error:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView.onResume()' on a null object reference`

Here is the Map fragment class:

```
public class Map extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    private MapView mapView;

public Map() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

    MapView mapView = (MapView) layout.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

            // Set map style
            mapboxMap.setStyleUrl(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS);

            // Set the camera's starting position
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(41.885, -87.679)) // set the camera's center position
                    .zoom(12)  // set the camera's zoom level
                    .tilt(20)  // set the camera's tilt
                    .build();

            // Move the camera to that position
            mapboxMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        }


    });
    return layout;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mapView.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mapView.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Am I missing something here? I was following this link: https://www.mapbox.com/help/first-steps-android-sdk/

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32601219/trying-to-put-a-map-in-a-fragment-activity/32601861#32601861

Comment: I am using Mapbox, would it still be the same way? @Boss

Comment: Nahh.. I 've found your issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two mapview instances. one is local variable inside oncreate method and another one is global variable.

And the global variable isn't initalized, So change this line

```
MapView mapView = (MapView) layout.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
```

into this

```
mapView = (MapView) layout.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
```

I think you understand the issue.